# using Sudo wth Gedit fails from XForwarded server

Tags: x11, sudo, xforwarding

The centos Server and ubuntu host machine both has gedit installed. Root login to the server is blocked and only a user can login via SSH through rsa keys.

When I log in to the server with *-X* supplied as parameter, I can use gedit like:
`gedit filename.txt &`
and the file opens in gedit for me to edit and save. But if I do Sudo to edit files then I get following error:

```
sudo gedit filename.txt &

[1] 11039
[user@server ~]$ X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

** (gedit:11040): WARNING **: Could not open X display
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

(gedit:11040): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0

[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo gedit filename.txt
```

How can I use Gedit in such situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sudoedit` command instead.

```
EDITOR=gedit sudoedit filename.txt
```

what this does is take a copy of the file, then runs the editor as you, then if it detects the file has changed copy the results back.

In most cases has the same effect as `sudo gedit filename.txt` but it runs the editor unprivileged and so your X forwarding should still work.

Comment: thanks but if I have to edit other files not just one file in such case?

Comment: You can do `sudoedit file1 file2 file3` and it'll make copies of all three files, call `$EDITOR tmpfile1 tmpfile2 tmpfile3` and then compare them for changes and copy back the changed ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an explanation, when you run `sudo` it resets a lot of environment variables, including `$HOME` which is reset to root's HOME (`/root` probably). When you run your X11 program it needs an XAUTHORITY magic cookie to allows it to connect to the DISPLAY. The appropriate cookie will have been placed by `ssh -X` in `~/.Xauthority` on the remote when you connected.

But after sudo your X11 program will look in `/root/.Xauthority`, and so get no cookie, or an old, stale, cookie.

Hence the *wrong authentication* messages you see. There are several solutions to preserve or restore `$HOME` after sudo, but for your particular case, it is wisest to use `sudoedit` as in the other answer.